# how the instanceof usage can be avoided?

Tags: java, instanceof

How can we avoid using `instanceof` operator for writing a clean code 
say for example:
If an object is of Type1 do something, but if it is of Type2 then do something else.

```
if(obj instanceof T1){
    doSomething()
 }else(obj instanceof T2){
    doOtherThing()
 }
```

Comment: You do know that it is `instanceof`, not `instanceOf`? You could implement a  [Chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern), where each element within the chain makes exactly one `instanceof` operation and consumes the event, if it fits. Maybe you should explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish since this seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It really depends on what the code is doing, what classes you have under your control (as opposed to third-party libraries where you can't abstract out interfaces), etc. Unfortunately, the question as it stands is too broad. The answer will generally use overridden methods, but the specifics are varied.

Comment: I personally prefer the`getClass()` method, say that the logic I am implementing requires to know the exact class not any superclass

Comment: Using `instanceOf` is not bad if it is simple and readable. If you want to hide it and use in more dynamic you can use [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example)

Comment: @Turing85: The question has been asked to understand how chain of instanceof operator is considered a code smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you use a series of `instanceof` with a cast to invoke a specific method that exists in a class but not in others :

```
if(obj instanceof T1){
    ((T1)obj) doSomething();
}
else(obj instanceof T2){
    ((T2)obj) doOtherThing();
}
```

To avoid that, if you can modify these classes, `T1` and `T2` should be subclasses of a common base class and the invoked method should be defined in the base class.
In this way, each subclass may implement it and you could so write :

```
obj.doSomething();
```

---

if you cannot modify these classes, you can always introduce an `Adapter` class that wraps them to provide a common way to invoke these methods.

**Adapter**

```
public interface Adapter{
    void process();
}
```

**AdapterForT1**

```
public class AdapterForT1 implements MyAdapter{

    private T1 adapted;
    public AdapterForT1(T1 adapted){
      this.adapted = adapted;
    } 

    public void process(){
       adapted.doSomething();
    }

}
```

**AdapterForT2**

```
public class AdapterForT2 implements MyAdapter{

    private T2 adapted;
    public AdapterForT2(T2 adapted){
      this.adapted = adapted;
    } 

    public void process(){
       adapted.doOtherThing();
    }

}
```

And you may use them in this way :

```
MyAdapter adapter = new AdapterForT1(obj);
...
adapter.process();
```

or :

```
MyAdapter adapter = new AdapterForT2(obj);
...
adapter.process();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **method overriding** here and then call the same function from different instances of different classes which will execute a different set of instructions as per implemented in individual classes

So for instance, you have a class T and then class T1 and class T2 both extends class T and all three classes implement executeTask function

So,

```
T t1 = new T1();
T t2 = new T2();

// this will execute function overridden in T1
t1.executeTask();

// this will execute function overridden in T2
t2.executeTask();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `interface`, which both classes implement. An interface is sort of a contract that every implementing class has to comply with.

With this you can ensure that every instance of such a class has all defined methods from that interface implemented.

For example:

```
public interface CustomExecutable {
    void execute();
}
```

Then your two classes:

```
public class T1 implements CustomExecutable {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // Do t1 logic
    }
}

public class T2 implements CustomExecutable {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // Do t2 logic
    }
}
```

In your main program you could do something like this:

```
CustomExecutable ce = new T1();
ce.execute(); // Does t1 logic
ce = new T2();
ce.execute(); // Does t2 logic
```

`instanceof` isn't necessary anymore, because each type has its own way of `execute`ing its code.